# System threads vs not-system threads

Tags: multithreading

I noted that very often it occurs expression: "system thread". What does it mean in the fact? In particular, I cannot imagine **not**-system threads. Just, the system must be aware of thread. The operating system ( a scheduler) switches a context so he must know it!

For example, on the fourth page it is written about system threads:
http://www.dabeaz.com/python/GIL.pdf

Comment: Please show us an example of the documentation you are referring to. Maybe a link?

Comment: This is actually a really interesting topic for game engines, where custom memory managers and thread schedulers are sometimes written to boost performance. This is somewhat of a outside case, because the game designers are optimizing these features to specific functions rather than optimizing for general purpose performance (or stability)

Answer (score 0):

A system thread is something provided by the OS.  The OS kernel is in charge of scheduling system threads.  If your runtime provides something like threads and a scheduler, then you have non-system threads.  These are often called green threads.  Sometimes non-system threads are more efficient, or the system doesn't provide threads.  For Python, examples of non-system threads would be provided by [greenlet](http://greenlet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Threads are a construct of the operating system, which is itself just a program, so one could implement a thread scheduler in another program on top of the OS if so they desire (usually they don't reinvent the wheel though). The pertinent components would likely include some interrupt mechanism, a memory manager (to virtualize memory allocation), and a priority queue of instruction pointers for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of green threads, event loops, cooperative multitasking and coroutines is generally what is meant by non-system threads.
It essentially refers to ways of structuring programs so that instead of blocking a thread to do things like IO, we allow the thread to be used by another task.
When we park a native thread, the OS can schedule another thread to use that CPU. With cooperative multitasking approaches it is also possible to have the application choose which task to execute next.

Comment: I would not put "green" threads in the same category as "event loops."  Green threads are _threads_:  Each one has its own execution context and its own call stack; and each one can be completely oblivious to what the others are doing (if that's what you want.)

Comment: Fair enough, but I would say they are at least related concepts.